# ERROR: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, dispatch

Trying to dispatch an action but i got this error in my terminal.

> ERROR: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

yet my code wont render on the screen.

```js
function CartPage(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [Total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [ShowTotal, setShowTotal] = useState(false);
  const [ShowSuccess, setShowSuccess] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cartItems = [];
    if (props.user.userData && props.user.userData.cart) {
      if (props.user.userData.cart.length > 0) {
        props.user.userData.cart.forEach((item) => {
          cartItems.push(item.id);
        });
        dispatch(getCartItems(cartItems, props.user.userData.cart)).then(
          (response) => {
            if (response.payload.length > 0) {
              calculateTotal(response.payload);
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }, [props.user.userData]);
}
```

Comment: Hi @braspy. You ask good questions. When you are happy with an answer, please be sure to select a "correct answer" to close the question (and reward the person who gave the best answer). When you reach 15 rep points, you also can upvote answers - which is another way to say thanks to the people who provided helpful answers. (Neither upvoting Nor choosing a correct answer cost *you* anything - but both actions give points to the people who gave the answers you reward.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linting rule `exhaustive-deps`. The purpose is to get you to only use props or state variables used in your second argument.

Because your second argument does not include `dispatch` you are getting an error. If you add dispatch to your second argument that should go away.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // your logic here 
}, [props.user.userData, dispatch])
```

The downside to this is that, your effect will run whenever your `userData` or `dispatch` changes. You can ignore this rule with `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.